# How to QP all PNRs on a queue at once in Sabre

Tags: sabre

I have a queue with over 1000 PNRs on it, and they all need to be sent to one specific queue for processing. Can I do this in one command or do I have to do individual QP

i've tried individual QP but it takes too long so I need something else.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.